# Can someone help clarify Aadhaar Biometric authentication API calls with sample code?

Tags: android, http, curl, aadhaar

I'm new to Aadhaar biometric APIs.

I am getting the below error message:

```
Proto Error code 810. (Missing biometrics in Authentication.)
```

using the following key and Morpho 1300 fingerprint reader:

> String bio = "Rk1SACAyMAAAAADkAAgAyQFnAMUAxQEAAAARIQBqAGsgPgCIAG0fRwC2AG2dSQBVAIUjPABuALShMgCxAL0jMAByAM6lPgCmAN2kQQBwAN8qNAB1AN8mPADJAOcgOQA8AOorNABoAOomOQC+AO2fMQDFAPqlSgCvAP8lRQB8AQuhPABwAQ4fMgB7ASqcRADAAS4iNwCkATMeMwCFATYeNwBLATYwMQBWATcoMQCkATecMQBEATwyMgBJAUciQQCkAU8cNQB9AVQWNgCEAVUVRACoAVgYOgBBAV69NgCsAWeYNwAA";

Following is the XML data format for authentication API:

```
<Auth uid=”” tid=”” ac=”” sa=”” ver=”” txn=”” lk=””>
 <Uses pi=”” pa=”” pfa=”” bio=”” bt=”” pin=”” otp=””/>
 <Tkn type=”” value=””/>
 <Meta udc=”” fdc=”” idc=”” pip=”” lot=”G|P” lov=””/>
 <Skey ci=”” ki=””>encrypted and encoded session key</Skey>
 <Data type=”X|P”>encrypted PID block</Data>
 <Hmac>SHA-256 Hash of Pid block, encrypted and then encoded</Hmac>
 <Signature>Digital signature of AUA</Signature>
</Auth>
```

When using PID block in XML format (which is the default), following is the format for “Pid” element:

```
<Pid ts=”” ver=””>
 <Demo lang=””>
 <Pi ms=”E|P” mv=”” name=”” lname=”” lmv=”” gender=”M|F|T” dob=””
  dobt=”V|D|A” age=”” phone=”” email=””/>
 <Pa ms=”E” co=”” house=”” street=”” lm=”” loc=””
  vtc=”” subdist=”” dist=”” state=”” pc=”” po=””/>
 <Pfa ms=”E|P” mv=”” av=”” lav=”” lmv=””/>
 </Demo>
 <Bios>
 <Bio type=”FMR|FIR|IIR” posh=””>encoded biometric</Bio>
 </Bios>
 <Pv otp=”” pin=””/>
</Pid>
```

Verify request

```
<Request requestId=”” version=”1.0” timeStamp=””>
 <Verify referenceUrl=”” maxResults=”” targetFMR=””>
 <Biometrics> <!-- Optional -->
 <Biometric type=”FMR|FIR|IIR”>
 Encoded (base64) biometric
 </Biometric>
 [...]
 </Biometrics>
 <Gallery>
 <referenceId id=””/>
 [...]
 </Gallery>
 </Verify>
</Request>
```

Verify Response

```
<Response requestId=”” timeStamp=””>
 <Return value=”” [failureReason=””]/>
 <CandidateList count=”” more=””>
 <Candidate referenceId=”” scaledScore=””/>
 [...]
 </CandidateList>
</Response>
```

Can someone help clarify Aadhaar Biometric authentication API call?

Comment: Can you provide any additional code that you use to access these APIs?

Comment: Using the Authentication API format detailed in Section 3.3 Page 11 of the Aadhaar API documentation (link provided above).

Comment: We'd prefer if we didn't have to grab a PDF to see the code you're using, so could you possibly edit that into your question?

Comment: Sure, @BradLarson. Adding it into the body of the question.

Comment: Is your fingerprint scanner Aadhar/UIDAI certified. I think I api requires the device key to be sent, which you can retrieve from only UIDAI certified fingerprint scanners.

Comment: @srikanthNutigattu Yes, its an AADHAAR/UIDAI certified Morpho sensor. (MSO 1300 E)